# Populate many-to-many intermediate table betwen two non spatial tables in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class

Is it possible to populate a many-to-many intermediate table between two non spatial tables in ArcGIS?

The intermediate table shows in ArcMap, but the origin and destination tables do not show in Attributes.

---

[EDIT]
Following the recommendations of @Ben S Nadler and the instructions in the link provided:

> Open the Attribute dialog box by clicking the Attributes button on
>   the Editor toolbar. The selected features will appear in the left
>   panel of the Attribute dialog box.

the Attribute dialog box does not show any tables and the intermediate table can not be populated.

The non spatial table to table many to many relation was finally simulated through creating the intermediate table and its fields manually and two one to many relations with it.

However, the relationship is therefore not working properly:

- the intermediate table can only be filled manually or relation by
  relation and,
- using the relation icon in the attribute tables of the
  origins only brings you to the intermediate table and therefore
  require one more step.

Comment: what do you mean by intermediate? why not use SQL?

Comment: @ziggy The intermediate table is the table which is created automatically when one creates a many to many relationship class. It contains the details about the relationship for the two related tables. Intermediate tables can be filled from ArcGIS for spatial data and I'd like to keep a consistent experience for the end user (also it would just be more practical)

Comment: I just performed a many-to-many join, in the Table View. The table view only shows the first joined record. However, if you export the table, the full many-to-many join will be preserved. You can create M-M table in ArcMap. This is separate from the Relationship Class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You define the m-m relationship with no attributes, so any new features can be related manually. You can then [populate the intermediate table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/populating-an-attributed-relationship-class-table-.htm) with the keys.
If you already have the keys you can define the relationship using the [Table to Relationship Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/table-to-relationship-class.htm) GP tool which will populate the intermediate table as well